# How do I save text from a textarea into a MySQL database with PHP when a Save button is clicked?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, save

I have a textarea in HTML where a logged in user can enter and save notes. I use the following script to retrieve the saved notes from the database

```
<?php
function notes() {
    $password = "fake_password";
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", $password) or die("Couldn't connect to the database!");
    mysql_select_db("db_name") or die("Couldn't find the database!");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE notes!=''");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $notes = $row['notes'];
        }

        echo $notes;
    }
}
?>
```

That works all fine and dandy but now - how do I save the changes the user made to the notes (textarea) when a Save button is clicked?

**EDIT:**

Here is the form itself:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <br />
        <center><textarea class="input-xxlarge" rows="15"><?php include('includes/func.php'); notes(); ?></textarea>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very broad. Begin reading [about `UPDATE` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), followed by the [`$_POST` superglobal in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) We don't have nearly enough information to give any kind of specific answer-- your form posts to PHP, you escape the input, and perform an `UPDATE` statement (or `INSERT` for new rows.

Comment: You have no `name=` attribute on the textarea, which means there's no way to get it from the `$_POST` variable when the form is submitted.  Also how/where are you tracking the user id?

Answer (score 2):

**First**: You should use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) to connect to your database, not mysql.  [Mysql is being deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), and is prone to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and therefore NOT safe to use in web applications.

With that caveat, I will reply using mysql since that is what you are using.

It's not too difficult.  Of course without the table structure, or the code from your form, the below has to use example field names, and assumes you store the user id in a `$_SESSION` variable:

```
<?php
    function savenotes() {
        // The database connection code should be moved to a central function/location rather than called in every function
        $password = "fake_password";
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", $password) or die("Couldn't connect to the database!");
        mysql_select_db("db_name") or die("Couldn't find the database!");

        // Retreive notes from form
        $notes = $_POST['notes']; // Assumes field is called notes, and you used method=POST
        // Assuming a user can only update their own notes, and that you are storing the user id somewhere
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid']; 
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET notes ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($notes) . "' WHERE userid = " . (int)$userid);


}
```

}
?>